# How can I pass down an array of objects as a prop to a component and then pass down the array's members as props to nested components?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vue-component

**At the bottom of this post in the edits I address what I want to accomplish and what has almost worked**

The following is my app with both the `<oo-upload>` and `<oo-uploads>` components defined above the app. Essentially `<oo-uploads>` displays a table of `<oo-upload>` components to build a file uploading plugin for my app. The `uploads` variable is a list of all uploads, and `upload` defines each individual upload.

```
<body>

    <script type="x/template" id="oo-upload-template">
        <td>@{{ upload.file.name }}</td>
        <td>@{{ upload.file.size }}</td>
        <td>
            <div class="ui indicating progress floated" v-progress="upload.progress">
                <div class="bar"><div class="progress"></div></div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class="ui primary button" v-on:click="upload" v-if="status < 1">Upload</button>
            <button class="ui red button" v-on:click="destroy" v-if="status == 2">Delete</button>
        </td>
    </script>

    <script type="x/template" id="oo-uploads-template">
        <table class="ui very basic table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="two wide">Filename</th>
                    <th class="two wide">Filesize</th>
                    <th class="ten wide">Status</th>
                    <th class="two wide">Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr v-show="uploads.length==0">
                    <td colspan="4" class="ui center aligned">No files added!</td>
                </tr>
                <tr v-for="upload in uploads">
                    <oo-upload :upload="upload"></oo-upload>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

            <tfoot class="full-width">
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="4">
                        <div class="ui right floated small green labeled icon button" v-on:click="uploadDialog">
                            <i class="plus icon"></i> Upload File
                            <input type="file" style="display:none;" v-el:uploader v-on:change="addFiles" multiple>
                        </div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </script>

    <div id="app">
        <div class="ui container">
            <oo-uploads :uploads="uploads"></oo-uploads>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

The issue is that an `objUpload` object is not being passed to each instance of the `<oo-upload>` component. Instead the Vue debugger says that the component is being passed a function, not an object. `<oo-uploads>` is not having any issues receiving `uploads` as a prop.

```
var Vue = require('vue'),
    VueRouter = require('vue-router'),
    VueResource = require('vue-resource'),
    Vuex = require('vuex'),
    VueValidator = require('vue-validator');

/*
PLUGINS
 */

Vue.use(VueResource);

/*
CUSTOM DIRECTIVES
 */

Vue.directive('progress', {
    bind: function () {
        $(this.el).progress();
    },
    update: function (value) {
        $(this.el).progress('set percent', value);
    }
});

/*
OBJECTS
 */

function objUpload (file) {
    this.progress = 0;
    this.file = file;
    this.status = 0;
}

/*
COMPONENTS
 */

Vue.component('oo-upload', {
    props: ['upload'],
    template: '#oo-upload-template',
    methods: {
        upload: function () {
            this.upload.status = 1;
            this.$http.post('/upload', this.upload.file, { progress: function (pe) {
                this.progress = Math.floor(pe.loaded/pe.total * 100);
            }}).then(function (result) {
                this.upload.status = 2;
            }, function (result) {
                this.upload.status = -1;
            })
        },
        destroy: function () {

        }
    }
});

Vue.component('oo-uploads', {
    props: ['uploads'],
    template: '#oo-uploads-template',
    methods: {
        uploadDialog: function () {
            $(this.$els.uploader).click();
        },
        addFiles: function () {
            var uploader = this.$els.uploader;
            for (var i = 0; i < uploader.files.length; i++) {
                var file = uploader.files[i];
                this.uploads.push(new objUpload(file));
            }
        }
    }
})

/*
CONSTANTS
 */

Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content');

/*
INSTANCE
 */

var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        uploads: [],
    },
});
```

EDIT: If I pass the `uploads` array directly to a single instance of `<oo-upload>` within `<oo-uploads>`, it passes the full array down just fine, but for some reason it won't iterate through the array and pass just the `objUpload` objects.

EDIT2: Essentially what I want to do is limit the scope of the data I pass down to only what is necessary for that component. I want the upload component acting only on the upload assigned to it. I recognize that my practice may be poor or that my implementation may not be possible, I just need a pointer as to how to accomplish something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Vue.js documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Fragment-Instance)

> It is therefore recommended to always have a single root-level, plain element in templates.

Try to wrap `oo-upload-template` with `tr` and change

```
<tr v-for="upload in uploads">
  <oo-upload :upload="upload"></oo-upload>
</tr>
```

to

```
<tr is="oo-upload" v-for="upload in uploads" :upload="upload"></tr>
```

[Example fixed fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pkawiak/zo2svtwm/1/)

Comment: Do you know why the rows are being displayed above the table instead of within <tbody> as rows?

Comment: Ouch, forgot about the dreaded table case... as stated in [docs](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Template-Parsing) _table can only contain thead, tbody, tfoot and tr, and these elements should be direct children of table_ because _custom tags will be hoisted out and thus not render properly_. I've updated the answer to use `is`

Comment: I made all of the changes that you suggested, but it didn't start working until I broke `upload` down and passed its properties individually as `<tr is="oo-upload" v-for="upload in uploads" :file="upload.file" :status="upload.status" :progress="upload.progress"></tr>`. I have no idea why though...